# jQuery Mobile doesn't show data-icon in iPhone iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.6.4 version, developing a mobile site and i have a data-icon that's not showing at all only in iOS 5  (so far from the feedback).

For the header:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="a">
<a data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-ajax="true" data-theme="a" data-inline="true" title="Back">Back</a>
<h1>Where can I travel</h1>
<a href="#" data-theme="a" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button" title="Home"></a>
```

This is the global icon css code that we are using:

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background:  #FFFFFF  /*{global-icon-color}*/;
    background:  transparent  /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
    background-image:  url(http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/images/icons-18-black.png)  /*{global-icon-set}*/;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Not only the header, but it's entire site that's using the global icon.

Any idea on this, guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue might be the retina display introduced in iphone 4S.To take care of retina display,we have to use icons with double the resolution.Try including this code in your css and see if there is any difference.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
    .ui-icon,
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
     background-image: url(images/icons-36-black.png);

}
}
```